# Chrome extension - remote page injection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension.

What I need to do is:

- *Read contents of specific div,*
- *Download contents from remote website.*
- *Replace current div contents with downloaded data.*

I'm informed that chrome prevents some of this-like interactions, but is there any way I can make this happen?
Injected JavaScript can not access remote website,
Content script cannot modify body of webpage
What can I do?

Comment: anyone? im lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Basic idea is:

CS = Content Script, defined in manifest.
FS = Injected Script - A separate script file.

1. Inject a script into the webpage (FS). This injection should happen in the CS. The FS than have full access to DOM and can manipulate it.
2. Use `window.addEventListener("message", function(){});` in CS. Use `window.postMessage({foo: "mydata"}, "*")` in FS or vice-versa. So you can post any data from and to the CS <=> FS. Loading the external data in the CS and send it to FS.

I've built some extensions with this technique and it works great.

Example:

**content-script.js**

```
var el = document.createElement('script');
el.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
el.setAttribute('src', "frontend-script.js");
document.head.appendChild(el);

window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    console.log(event);
}, false);
```

**frontend-script.js**

```
window.postMessage({
    "foo": "data-from-frontend-script"
}, "*");
```

Comment: This seems to work, just a little question, sorry for being new:

i'm sending message from **FS** to **CS** to kick it in,

**CS** sends data back to **FS**.

Can you replace 'console.log(event)' with 'alert('data-from-frontend-script');'? Im not sure how to rip data from event object.

Comment: I've figured it out, missed **data** container. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a problem with this code. It seems to be it's able to communicate only one way :(
**FS**
`window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
 alert(event.data.msg2);
}, false);
window.postMessage({
    "msg1": "request"
}, "*");`

**CS**
`window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    console.log(event);
 
window.postMessage({
    "msg2": "response"
}, "*");
}, false);`

**response** (msg2) never arrives :(

Comment: It does work, i have this things in multiple extensions. However, i cannot debug it for you when i don't have your full extension code. Your FS, CS and manifest.json.

Comment: Can you provide me with all three of them? The content doesn't really matter as long as FS (!NOT! CS) sends something like "request" and CS sends back "response", then FS pops up alert saying "response"... I don't really care if CS or Background responds to messages from FS

Comment: can you provide me with links for those extensions so i can look at the source?

Comment: @Andriuxa https://github.com/brainfoolong/greaterfield - Look at `init.js`, `inject.js` and `gf.js` (at the bottom and also search for `window.postMessage`).

Comment: @Andriuxa Please vote the answer as accepted if it had helped you.